Fitting a parabola through two points, minimizing the error in the derivative in those two points.
Let $f(x)$ be a parabola and $f'(x)$ its derivative.
Given are the known points $(p, q)$ and $(r, s)$:
$q = f(p)$ and $s = f(r)$.
Also given are the values of the desired derivatives
in $p$ and $r$. Lets say $t$ and $u$.
In the ideal case, we want to find an $f$ such that
$f'(p) = t$ and $f'(r) = u$. However, that might not be possible
if no such quadratic polynomial exists for $f$.
How to find a parabola $f(x)$ such that $f(p) = q$, $f(r) = s$
and $f'(p)$ and $f'(r)$ are such that the error in both is
equal?
One way to define this error is by looking at the
angle the tangents make; aka a vertical line deviates the same amount from $y=x$ as a horizontal line; even though the derivatives are infinity, 1 and 0 respectively. But I'm happy with other definitions as well if that makes the equations easier. For example, just looking at the difference between the values of the derivatives: $|f'(r) - u| = |f'(p) - u|$.
EDIT:
My attempt was as follows:
Let $f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c$, with derivative $f'(x) = 2a x + b$.
This gives, with regard to the derivative constraints:
$2p a + b = t\\
2r a + b = u$
or
$\begin{bmatrix}
2p & 1 \\
2r & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
t \\
u
\end{bmatrix}$
For which we can solve
$\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b
\end{bmatrix} =
\frac{1}{2(p-r)}
\begin{bmatrix}
t - u \\
2pu - 2rt
\end{bmatrix}$
Now we can calculate
$f(p) - f(r) = a (p^2 - r^2) + b (p - r)$
Realizing that this difference really should have been $q - s$, the function can be corrected by adding a linear function to it. In other words, adjusting $b$ by adding $\frac{q - s - (a (p^2 - r^2) + b (p - r))}{p - r}$ to it.
This then leads to:
$a = \frac{t - u}{2(p - r)} \\
b = \frac{pu−rt}{p - r} + \frac{q - s - (\frac{t - u}{2(p - r)} (p^2 - r^2) + \frac{pu−rt}{p - r} (p - r))}{p - r} =
\frac{pu−rt+q-s+\frac{(u-t)(p+r)}{2}+rt-pu}{p - r}=
\frac{2q-2s+(u-t)(p+r)}{2(p-r)}$
From which c trivially follows.
Strangely enough this is not equal to what xpaul did get...
Edit2
I was forced to reformulate my question, which is now posted here: Fitting a parabola through two points in which the derivatives are known with the aim of finding a minimum.

May I suggest you write the four équations in your post ? At least we should use thé samedi notations. Also make thé contraints fully explicit.

Next time, just put math expressions inside two $ signs.

I verified the above formula's with a C++ program and it produces the correct result (so no errors or typos this time).

The following posts are related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594465 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243072 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791927 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977306

Let
$$ f(x)=a(x-p)^2+b(x-p)+c. $$
Then
$$ f'(x)=2a(x-p)+b. $$
Then $f(p)=q$ and $f(r)=s$ imply $c=q$ and
$$ a(r-p)^2+b(r-p)+q=s. \tag1$$
Also $|f'(p) - t| = |f'(q) - u|$ implies
$$ |b-t|=|2a(q-p)+b-u| $$
or
$$ 2a(q-p)+b-u=\pm(b-t). \tag2 $$
It is easy to solve $a$ and $b$ from (1) and (2). In fact,
Case 1: Take "+" in (2). Then
$$ a= \frac{t-u}{2 p-2 q},b= \frac{p^2-2 p r+q+r^2-s}{p-r}. $$
Case 2: Take "-" and then (1) and (2) become
\begin{eqnarray}
\bigg\{\begin{array}
 ((r-p)^2a+(r-p)b=s-q,\\
(q-p)a+b=\frac12(t+u),
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
which gives
$$ a= \frac{2 p^2-p (4 r+t+u)+2 q+2 r^2+r t+r u-2 s}{2 (p-q) (p-r)},b= \frac{p^2-2pr+q+r^2-s}{p-r}. $$

Thanks! I did make some typos when entering my question, which probably made it into your answer (for example, your Case 1 $a$ divides by $2p - 2q$ - that can't be right, and probably should be $2p - 2r$. I editted the question to fix some errors I had, and added my own derivation. Strangely enough, I get something different for $b$ :/.

I tried to edit your answer and fix it. You put a $q$ instead of an $r$ in the beginning, which after changing that make the formula for $a$ correct, but after that I lost what you did for $b$. Deriving $b$ from (1) make it depend on $a$, and $a$ depends on $t-u$, but neither $t$ nor $u$ appear in your $b$.

You can edit it.

I can - but I don't know how you got to $b = \frac{p^2 - 2pr + r^2 - s}{p-r}$. I could redo the whole derivation myself, but then it isn't your answer anymore. Clearly it came from (1), but that gives me: $b = \frac{s - q - a(r-p)^2}{r-p} = \frac{a (p - r)^2 +q - s}{p-r}$ ... Oh well, I guess you just left the $a$ out.
