# How to find equation of parabola with diagonal directrix

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, analytic-geometry

I was taking the 2014 AMC 12A test when I came upon #25, which is as follows:

> The parabola $P$ has focus $(0,0)$ and goes through the points $(4,3)$ and $(-4,-3)$.  For how many points $(x,y)\in P$ with integer coordinates is it true that $|4x+3y|\leq 1000$?

I got that the directrix of this (rotated) parabola was $y=\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{25}{4}$ but I got stuck there. I was able to understand from [the solutions on AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2014_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_25#Problem) and [the solution in this video from AoPS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAQNcQoRuVo) that I should rotate the parabola using rectangular to polar coordinate transformations and back. I think that it is a clever way to solve such a problem, but is there any quicker method or formula that when given the focus and directrix (which is tilted), I can easily find the equation of the parabola?

I have also seen and read [this previously asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045286/find-tilted-parabola-equation-given-vertex-and-angle) if anyone was wondering.

Comment: There are two parabolas that fit the quoted description.

Comment: Yes for this specific problem but given the directrix there would only be one parabola.

Comment: You wrote ”**the** directrix” when there are two possibilities. Is there more to the problem than what you’ve quoted that would allow you to eliminate one?

Comment: No there isn't any more information but I think both parabolas could solve the problem because of their symmetry and the absolute value in $|4x+3y|\le 1000$. Ultimately, my question is not about the specific problem I was solving, but actually my desire to generalize the solution to other problems involving tilted parabolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definition of a parabola is that it is the locus of points equidistant from a fixed point (the focus) and a fixed line (the directrix). So, if you know the focus $(x_f,y_f)$ and directrix $ax+by+c=0$, then using the standard formulas for distance to a point and a line, you can write down an equation for the parabola directly: $$(x-x_f)^2+(y-y_f)^2={(ax+by+c)^2\over a^2+b^2}.$$